# Storm: Min/max aggregation across several sliding windows with varying sizes

Tags: apache-storm

I wonder what the best practice is to approach the following problem in Apache Storm.

I have a single spout that generates a stream of integer values with an explicit timestamp attached. The goal is to perform min/max aggregation with three sliding windows over this stream:

- last hour
- last day, i.e. last 24 hours

Last hour is easy:

```
topology.setBolt("1h", ...)
    .shuffleGrouping("spout")
    .withWindow(Duration.hours(1), Duration.seconds(10))
    .withTimestampField("timestamp"));
```

However, for longer periods I am concerned about the queue sizes of the windows. When I consume the tuples directly from the spout as with the last-hour aggregation, every single tuple would end up in the queue.

One possibility would be to consume the tuples from the pre-aggregated "1h" bolt. However, since I am using explicit timestamps, late tuples arriving from the "1h" bolt are ignored. A 1 hour lag is not an option as this delays the evaluation of the window. Is there a way to "allow" late tuples without impacting the timeliness of the results?

Of course I could also store away an aggregate every hour and then compute the minimum over the last 24 hours including the latest value from the "1h" stream. But I am curious if there is a way to do this properly using Storm means.

## Update 1

Thanks to arunmahadevan's answer I changed the 1h min bolt to emit the minimum tuple with the maximum timestamp of all tuples in the respective 1h window. That way the consuming bolt does not discard the tuple due to late arrival. I also introduced a new field `original-timestamp` to retain the original timestamp of the minimum tuple.

## Update 2

I finally found an even better way by only emitting state changes in the 1h min bolt. Storm does not advance the time in the consuming bolt as long as no new tuples are received hence the late arrival issue is prevented. Also, I get to keep the original timestamp without copying it into a separate field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think periodically emitting the min from "1h" to "24h" bolt should work and keep the "24h" queue size in check.

If you configure a lag, the bolt's execute is invoked only after that lag (i.e. when the event time cross the sliding interval + lag).

Lets say if the "1h" bolt is configured with a lag of 1 min, the execute will be invoked for the tuples between 01:00 - 02:00 only after event time crosses 02:01. (i.e. the bolt has seen an event with timestamp >= 02:01). The execute will however only receive the tuples between 01:00 and 02:00.

Now if you compute the last one hour minimum and emit the result to a "24h" bolt that has a sliding interval of say 1 hr and lag=0, it will trigger once incoming event's timestamp crosses the next hr. If you emitted the 01:00-02:00 min with a timestamp of 02:00 the "24h" window will trigger (for the events between the previous day 02:00 to 02:00) as soon as it receives the min event since the event time crossed the next hour and the configured lag is 0.

Comment: OK the crucial part of your answer that really helped me is to emit the minimum with the max timestamp of the window under consideration.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to achieve the same for average aggregation? This is different because I cannot use a sliding window on the 1h bolt because this would cause the same tuples to be incorporated multiple times in the average. Is there a way to combine a tumbling window based pre-aggregation with the latest elements from the source spout? I would somehow need to evict the source spout elements from the queue once they are covered by an aggregate that is coming from the tumbling window. But there seems to be no possibility for custom eviction policies in Storm...